# Why can I not connect to my Oracle Cloud ADB with python-oracledb?

Tags: python, oracle, python-oracledb

I am working with Python 3.9.13 cx_Oracle on my Always Free Oracle ADB without problems.

Now I am trying to connect with python-oracledb on the Oracle ADB without success:

- sqlplus -l admin@'*tcps://adb.eu-frankfurt-oraclecloud.com:1522/abc_db21cpresent_medium.adb.oraclecloud.com?wallet_location=C:/etc_atp21c-present*'

  => works.
- *csx = "tcps://adb.eu-frankfurt-oraclecloud.com:1522/abc_db21cpresent_medium.adb.oraclecloud.com?wallet_location=C:\etc_atp21c-present&retry_count=20&retry_delay=3"*

  *connection = oracledb.connect(user='northwind', password='*****', dsn=csx)*

  => doesn't work: the `oracledb.connect` doesn't come back (no errors).

Are there any hints for this?

Fried

Answer (score 0):

It works now:

you have to specify three parameters (Windows 10):

```
connection = oracledb.connect(user='northwind', password=pw, dsn='db21cpresent_medium',
                         config_dir="c:\\my\\wallet\\dir",
                         wallet_location="c:\\my\\wallet\\dir", 
                         wallet_password=wpw
 )
```

In my wallet-dir there are the tnsname.ora and ewallet.pem files after unzipping of the wallet.zip file.

Fried

Comment: The above is true for the default Thin mode of python-oracledb, not for Thick mode.  See a fuller answer on the duplicate post https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4499053/oracledb-does-not-work-in-python-3-9-13-on-cloud-adb